# Mozilla Thunderbird + Lightning: a task with a shell command line

Tags: command-line, thunderbird, tasks, lightning

In Thunderbird [Lightning](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/calendar/), I created a repeating task to remind me to perform a back-up of files.

Is it possible to have a command line to run the software in the text of the task? (I use [Toucan](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/toucan) to do the back-up.)